# Pairwise deletion in regression

Tags: r, time-series, multiple-regression, missing-data, unbalanced-classes

I'm conducting a research on R to study how variables like coal, wind, solar, hydro generation, demand and weather variables (independent variables) affect the energy price (dependent variable) for one country in a time frame of 2000-2020.
For what concern wind and solar energy generation, since those plants have been recently installed in this country, the values are only available from 2014 to 2020, while from 2000 to 2013 I have missing values due to the fact that neither wind nor solar plants were installed at that time.

My goal is to do a regression that somehow understand the fact that before 2014, the price was only influenced by variables such as coal, gas, hydro generation and demand, while from 2014 it was also affected by these new technologies (solar and wind).

I've tried using the `lm()` function on R, but the problem is that only CC (Complete Cases) are considered, thereby each time the observations for wind and solar generations are not provided, that date is discarded and I would only study the price when all generations were available.
I tried with the function `lmac()`, that is supposed to perform regression with Available Cases, but it doesn't provide a full regression output as the one of `lm()` and moreover I didn't understand how to implement time dummies within the model (like `lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + factor(time), data=dt)`.

Is there any suggestions on how to proceed with this kind of dataset? It would be really appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand your description of the data you have and why you've chosen lm(). But regarding the missing data, it seems to me appropriate to set the missing wind/solar covariates to be 0.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! However, I think that plugging 0 instead of NaN for wind/solar covariates would be misleading since the generation was actually not zero but it didn't exist at all (no wind/solar plants built before 2014).

Comment: This is where my lack of understanding your model will matter, so you might be correct. But, how are "no wind power generated" and "wind power didn't exist" different, in terms of the relation to price? It seems to me like those have the same meaning in total power generated, and therefore in terms of the price. Consider: what if there was some extreme volcano cloud that meant in 2022 there was no solar power. Do you believe the "potential" for solar power to be generated will have an influence the price, even though there isn't actually any solar power being generated in 2022?